Why does node-gyp action mc report error message?
I'm on windows platform. I have a node-gyp config like below.
'actions': [
     {
        'action_name': 'genereate mc',
        'inputs': ['<(module_root_dir)/src/test.mc'],
        'outputs': [
            '<(module_root_dir)/src/test.h',
            '<(module_root_dir)/src/test.rc',
        ],
        'action': ['mc <@(_inputs) -h ../src -r ../src'],
     },
 ],

When compile, the vcxproj it generated:
<ItemGroup>
    <CustomBuild Include="c:\test\src\test.mc">
      <FileType>Document</FileType>
      <Command>call call &quot;mc C:\\test\src\test.mc -h ..\src -r ..\src&quot;&#xD;&#xA;if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%</Command>
      <Message>genereate mc</Message>      
      <Outputs>c:\test\src\test.h;c:\test\src\test.rc</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
  </ItemGroup>

It will report below error message:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I tried to replace all parameters of mc to full path, but it still report this error.
